# How to visually position image before heading element

Tags: css, html

Quite often we find ourselves wanting to do this:

```
<section class="product">
    <img src="/images/widget.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="A Widget" />
    <h2>A Widget</h2>
    <p>Here's the description of a great widget</p>
</section>
```

Semantically the above is wrong because I believe the image should come after the heading, rather than before it.  To get round this issue I've always done something like this:

```
<section class="product">
    <h2>A Widget</h2>
    <img src="/images/widget.jpg" width="300" height="200" alt="A Widget" />
    <p>Here's the description of a great widget</p>
</section>
```

...and then CSS as follows:

```
.product {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 220px;
}

.product img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

This means the HTML markup is in a better order, but visually the image appears before the heading, which is what I want.

The problem is that now I am making responsive websites, the image width (and height) can scale to an unknown size.  This means that it's not possible to know how much padding to apply to the top of the container to accommodate the absolutely positioned image.

Is there another solution, other than to place the image before the heading, which feels dirty, dirty, dirty to me.

Comment: If you really want to be semantic, use `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For situations like this, I'd forgo the very minor semantic issue and order the elements in such a way that requires the least amount of trickery to put them where I want them. In your case, I'd let the `img` come before the `h1` and leave it at that.

However, if you were dead set on ordering them "correctly", you could use jQuery to dynamically change the `padding-top` in your example, based on the height of the img in question.

[Here's an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/Hxr7y/).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the ratio of the image you could try to work with percentages.

```
.product {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 66%; 
    /* The ratio of the image is 3/2 (300x200). 
       When 100% wide it's 66% high. So you can add padding of 66%. */
}

.product img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

And remove width="" and height="" in the img tag.

```
<section class="product">
  <h2>A Widget</h2>
  <img src="/images/widget.jpg" alt="A Widget" />
  <p>Here's the description of a great widget</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea.  However I tried it and the 66% ends up at 66% of the height of the parent element, not the height of the image :(